# Is this considered a serial downvote?

Tags: discussion, support, serial-voting

5 of my answers were all downvoted today. I have reason to believe that this was not a coincidence? What action can be taken?

[image]

These questions are relatively far apart time wise. I'm assuming that 5 downvotes all of a sudden in one day is not a normal event?

Why would 5 of my posts be downvoted on the same day when they are not related to eachother and are posted at different time in the past? I don't think it is a coincidence?

Dates of posts:

- Aug 20
- Aug 13
- Jun 25
- Feb 15
- Feb 19

As you can see the spreadness of the dates is supporting of my reason to suspect it is serial downvoting.

Comment: Were they posted recently or quite a while ago? If they were posted a while ago, then it's probably serial downvoting.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar A while ago

Comment: Any voting pattern which occur within a very short timespan (say, a few seconds between each vote -- but actual numbers are a secret part of the watchdog process) is essentially serial voting. This will be reversed within six hours from now.

Comment: Don't make the Cereal mad. It is downvotes for vengeance. Damn the grass!

Comment: The voting will likely be reversed by tomorrow. If it is not, contact the moderators. Users who have been serially downvoting others are made note of. I think such users are given one or two warnings before either having their account suspended or outright deleted.

Comment: @CameronWilliams In [another post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16666/some-of-my-answers-downvoted-unnecessarily/16669#16669) a mod said, that we should not contact moderators in such cases. Instead the community managers should be contacted using the contact us link. Here is related meta.SE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed/212339#212339

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yeah my bad! I guess reddit ruined me. I overuse the word mod now.

Comment: At a glance it appears that 3 of the 5 downvotes were undone by serial downvoting reversal mechanism.  Since all five occurred within a fairly short timeframe, it's reasonable to think all of these were connected.

Comment: @hardmath Yes. This is my train of thought however reading around I have found that it may just be best to ignore the -4 rep.

Comment: @Alizter: Now that the serial downvoting reversal "automatic" mechanism has run, I think it would be appropriate to send Community Managers a note with the links to your Answers, as Martin outlines above.  It's possible that human eyes on this example may improve the mechanism going forward for all of us.